# How to make Jobs run once in same time?

Tags: go

When I receive a channel, sometimes the value of the channel I get is the same so that it makes Gocron make the same job. Is there a way to work around this?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
    "time"

    "github.com/go-co-op/gocron"
)

func main() {
    for {
        channel := make(chan string)
        go func() {
            channel <- "19:59"
            channel <- "19:59"
            channel <- "19:59"

        }()

        for data := range channel {
            s := gocron.NewScheduler(time.Now().Location())
            dd := strings.Split(data, ",")

            for i, dt := range dd {
                fmt.Println(dt, i)
                s.Every(1).Day().At(dt).SingletonMode().Do(task)

            }
            s.StartAsync()
        }
    }

}

func task() {
    fmt.Println("RUNNNNNNN")
}
```

Comment: Hm, you _are_ pushing the same values, though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `map` to track whether the same timestamp has been processed already.

```golang
func main() {
    records := make(map[string]struct{}) // a tracking records

    for {
        channel := make(chan string)
        go func() {
            channel <- "19:59"
            channel <- "19:59"
            channel <- "19:59"
        }()

        for data := range channel {
            // check for existence
            if _, ok := records[data]; !ok {
                records[data] = struct{}{} // add this record

                s := gocron.NewScheduler(time.Now().Location())
                dd := strings.Split(data, ",")

                for i, dt := range dd {
                    fmt.Println(dt, i)
                    s.Every(1).Day().At(dt).SingletonMode().Do(task)
                }
                s.StartAsync()
            }
        }
    }
}
```